# How do I unlock radio after changing battery in 2009 Honda Accord EXL?

Tags: honda, audio, accord

Hi everyone okay so I changed the battery of my car and the antitheft system reset. I cannot get into my radio for the life of me. I called the previous owner and he said he took the radio out before and got the serial number with the vin and looked up the code and got two different codes. I asked for the number and went online to double check myself and at the dealership.

I have reset my battery a total of 6 times already because I know the radio will permentally lock after 6 errors. I have tried the codes numerous of times and have even gone to the dealership and They tried the 1&6 plus power and what came up was S/N No Code meaning it’s not showing the serial number but I do have it because the radio was taken out before. The advisor said he worked at Honda for over 10 years and has never seen a radio say “S/N No code.

The previous owner said he tried multiple of times and almost gave up but tried one of the codes one last time and by luck, it unlocked. I have tried it so many times and it cannot go through. I tried looking up videos on how to bypass the system by holding the power button on the Honda radio but unfortunately, I believe this bypass is for newer models.

Can anyone tell me how to unlock my radio?

Comment: Is there not a sticker with the security code on the side of the glove box? When you first power on the radio after the reset does it display: Code Error 1? I'm thinking if it's not displaying a serial number it may of lost it's calibration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the 4 digit number code, which can be available from the manufacture of the vehicle, by using the VIN number of your vehicle. Some owners enter this code in your manual, in the radio section.  Good luck.